# App is incompatible with all of your devices

Tags: android, sdk, compatibility, apk, google-play

I'm trying to track down an issue that has just popped up.  I have an app that one of my users purchased back in September that has worked fine.  He has since wiped out his phone, and re-installed the stock rom.  Now, for some reason, when he goes to install my app, the Android Market tells him its not compatible with his phone.

He has a Samsung Galaxy S.  Looking at the statistics for my app on the Android development site, I'm showing 137 users who have installed the app on their Samsung Galaxy S's.

Since he purchased the app, I have released a couple of updates, including one a few days ago.    The update from a few days ago was minor, but, it was done after a fresh re-install of my laptop, eclipse and Android SDK.  This was the first update I did with ICS sdk installed as well.

How can I track down this issue?  The app is just a simple soundboard, nothing complicated.

Comment: Has he tried installing other applications?

Comment: Maybe his stock ROM contained an older version of Android? That's the way it was for me once - phone came with 1.6 by default, but could be updated to 2.2. Can you check version numbers with the customer?

Answer (score 1):

Few thoughts, first read up on how your app is configured for availability in marketplace. Maybe while submitting it you made a mistake.

Second, look at the way Android uses manifest file to say that app X requires minimum version, say 1.6 of Android, and the also how it uses manifest file to do set target sdk (basically read up on manifest file settings `minsdkversion`, `targetsdkversion`).

Lastly get the user's Android version, and try running your app on that version of Android emulator, if you can do that on handset it is better, but emulator should suffice. Good Luck.

Comment: Originally when i first released the app, it was built against targetsdkversion of 1.6 (target 4).  However, I started getting requests from people to have the ability to move the app to their SD card.  So, after doing some reading up, I found out I had to set the build target to Android 2.2, but in order to maintain compatibility with 1.6 (which I do have some customers running), I had to keep the minsdkversion at 4.  Also, this particular customer is running Android v2.3.6 which is the same version running on my phone that I test it on.  I emailed him the APK to test it, and it works...

Comment: So, it looks like you changed targetsdkversion from 1.6 to 2.2 and this is causing the error. Try setting only minsdkversion to 1.6 in manifest (while removing targetsdkversion line). It should work on all Android 1.6+ devices, while allowing people the ability to move the app to SD card on handsets that support that. Also try this with setting maxsdkversion too.